# QGIS map creation: google imagery as base-map displaced when printed to pdf of tiff

Tags: qgis, google-maps, cartography

I want to create a set of maps using the QGIS atlas feature.
It works quite well, however when printing the maps to an image or pdf, the base map (google maps areal imagery) is shifted under the rest of the map.

The screenshots show (a) the correct representation in the print composer and (b) the defective map I get when printing to .tiff. Is there any workaround on this issue?

[image]
(a) correct map in print composer

[image]
(b) defective map printed to .tiff

Comment: how did you load the google maps?

Comment: I loaded it with the open layers plugin.
In the meantime I found that I could produce correct maps by try and error-moving the map frame around. While this helped, I didn't really understand under which conditions I can omit the base-map shift, which still is rather unsatisfactory.

Comment: don't use the openlayers plugin it's broken use QuickMapServices instead.